# Listview with checkedtextview

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I have two questions:

1. If I am using `CheckedTextView` in a `ListView` and my class only extends `Activity` (instead of `ListActivity`), since I have another button at the bottom below my `ListView`,
   what event should I listen on, when a checkbox is selected in the `CheckedTextView`?
2. If I extend my class to use `ListActivity`, I can use `onListItemClick` event, right? How can I add a new button to this type of layout?

Here is my code..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    m_versionText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.versionText);
    m_versionText.setText("Android Version is:" + Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    m_btnAllCalendars = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_allCalendars);
    m_btnAllCalendars.setOnClickListener(mCalendarListener);
    m_calendarList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.calList);

    //populateList uses simplecursoradapter to add items to the listview..(this part is working)

    populateList();
    m_calCheckText = (CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.calTextView);
    m_calCheckText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
        if (((CheckedTextView)v).isChecked())
        {
            Log.d(TAG,"i am inside ...its checked");
        }
    }

    });

     private void populateList(){

        Log.d(TAG,"inside populateList");
        Cursor cursor = getAllCalendars();
        startManagingCursor(cursor);

        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.cal_list,cursor,new String[]{"displayName"},new int []{R.id.calTextView});
        //m_calendarList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        m_calendarList.setAdapter(adapter);
      }

 }
```

UPDATE:::

```
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.cal_list,cursor,new String[]{"displayName"},new int []{R.id.calTextView});
        m_calendarList=getListView();
        m_calendarList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        m_calendarList.setAdapter(adapter);
        m_calendarList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position,long id)
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"I am inside onItemClick and position is:"+String.valueOf(position));
            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)view;
    the below code didnt work too           
          //CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.layout.cal_list);
                ctv.setChecked(!ctv.isChecked());

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
m_calendarList.setAdapter(adapter);
m_calendarList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // do something here...
        // m_calendarList.getCheckedItemPosition(); will also give you the position
    }
});
```

EDIT:

```
m_calendarList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position,long id) {
        View v = m_calendarList.getChildAt(position);
        CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.cal_id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am able to get the position of the listitem click alright.....but how do i get/set the state of the checkbox that is inside each listitem from the onItemClick method???

Comment: Ah... I see. Do you want to get/set the state of an arbitrary check-box in the list or the very one that was clicked? The `view` parameter to the `onItemClick()` function should be the one that was just clicked. NOTE! that there is a difference between `setOnItemClickListener` and `setOnClickListener` especially when the list is implementing clickable items (such as the CheckedTextView)

Comment: i want the very one that was clicked...when i try to cast the view from onListItemClick to a checkedTextView, and try to set that textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked()); my app crashes.

Comment: Yes it does crash because you're using the `m_calCheckText.setOnClickListener`. You should try to use the `setOnItemClickListener` instead (that is the on-ITEM-click-listener).

Comment: i am actually not using both..i am extending my class to ListActivity(instead of activity) and i am calling it on onListItemClick(ListView l,View  v, int position,long id);

Comment: I seem to have the same sort of issue faced here [link](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/7372b92dfa50ee33/70d0eb8f51ea8b26) The view i get inside onListItemClick is of type LinearLayout and its not able to cast to a checkedTextView . Looks like i may have to rewrite my code.

Comment: Yes, it's a `LinearLayout` because your custom list item is most likely built with a `LinearLayout`. You could try `view.findViewById(R.id.myCheckedTextViewId)` to retrieve the CheckedTextView in question

Comment: i tried that and it still crashed...i found this [link](http://tokudu.com/2010/android-checkable-linear-layout/) that i am going to use. Hopefully that will work

Comment: I have used that very same link my self. Actually my code example from above originates from that link. Very useful one :-)

Comment: ok i think i am making progress...but inside the OnItemClickListener of onItemClick, how do i get the state of the checkbox ??..I am still getting the linearlayout in the view and if i try to cast it to checkedtextview, i am getting an error

Comment: You shouldn't cast it CheckedTextView. You should use it to find the CheckedTextView inside it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CheckedTextView.setOnClickListener() Inside the onClick() method of your listener you can use CheckedTextView.isChecked() to find out whether it was it was checked or unchecked.

Edit: Here is an example of the getView() method for your Adapter.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }
        m_calCheckText = (CheckedTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.calTextView);
        m_calCheckText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                if (((CheckedTextView)v).isChecked())
                {
                   Log.d(TAG,"i am inside ...its checked");
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Comment: My app just crashes, if i try to set a onclicklistener for my checkedTextView. I am calling the method after i populate the list.

Comment: Post the code you are using. And the output from the LogCat would be useful also.

Comment: I am getting a nullpointerexception on this line  m_mycheckTextView = (CheckedTextView)findViewById(R.id.myCheckText) where m_mycheckTextView is a private variable of type checkedtextview.

Comment: Try doing m_mycheckTextView = (CheckedTextView)m_calendarList.findViewById(R.id.myCheckText);       You can also attach the Listeners to your CheckedTextViews inside your populateList() method using the ListAdapter.

Comment: i am still getting m_calCheckText as null ..not sure why

Comment: If no one answers I'll post an example a bit later when I am back home.

Comment: after some struggles, i was able to extend my class to a listactivity and i had to define my main.xml with a @android:id/list listview and was able to get it to work. But i am not sure this is the right way to handle it. Now i have a overridden procedure onListItemClick, which does get called, but i am not sure how to get the state of the check box. Also since listview gets recycled (upon scrolling), how to preserve the state?? Please post your example as well. I will be interested to see how you do it. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: I am directly using simplecursoradapter to fetch the data into my listview .. is it necessary for me to extend my simplecursoradapter and write the getview method?