# Using CheckedTextView with setOnItemClickListener Error

Tags: android-listfragment, onitemclicklistener, checkedtextview

I'm trying to use a *CheckedTextView* with *OnItemClickListener* in order to be able to click on a list item and "check" the row that was just clicked. I'm using a SimpleAdapter in a SherlockListFragment. The CheckedTextView state will then be saved in SharedPreferences for future user usage in the app.

I have looked all over to find a clear solution, but I don't figure it out. My code is based on: [Listview with checkedtextview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5034362/listview-with-checkedtextview). Here is the error message I get:

*"The method setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type View"*

I do import android.view.View.OnClickListener, android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,android.widget.CheckedTextView, android.widget.AdapterView. Here is my code:

Thanks a lot for your help!

public class SettingsFragment extends SherlockListFragment  implements ActionBar.TabListener {

```
 // Array of strings storing settings names
String[] settings_names = new String[] {
    "Bluetooth",
    "Speakerphone",
    "test3",
    "test4"
};

// Array of integers points to icons stored in /res/drawable-ldpi/
int[] settings_icons = new int[]{
    R.drawable.device_access_bluetooth,
    R.drawable.device_access_call,
    R.drawable.device_access_alarms,
    R.drawable.device_access_location_found
};

// Array of strings to store settings description
String[] settings_desc = new String[]{
    "Activate Bluetooth connection",
    "Enable Speakerphone",
    "Enable ...",
    "Enable ..."
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){

    // Each row in the list stores country name, currency and flag
    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("set", settings_names[i]);
        hm.put("desc", settings_desc[i]);
        hm.put("icon", Integer.toString(settings_icons[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "icon","set","desc" };

    // Ids of views in settingsrow_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.setting_icon,R.id.setting_name,R.id.setting_desc};


    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.settingsrow_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.settingsrow_layout, from, to);

    /** Setting the array adapter to the listview */
    setListAdapter(adapter);


    // The list is identify by and ID in the xml file        
    final View thelist = container.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    thelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position,long id) {
            View v = ((ViewGroup) thelist).getChildAt(position);
            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.setting_name);
            ctv.setChecked(!ctv.isChecked());
        }
    });


   LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.settingsfragment_layout,
            container, false);

    return mLinearLayout;
}
```

}

Here is the row xml file used by the adapter:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/setting_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/center_text_zone"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/setting_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="false" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/setting_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="12sp"/>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout >
```

Comment: I have added the xml file used by the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

The method `setOnItemClickListener` belongs to the `AdapterView` class.
`AdapterView` extends `View`.

However, your object `thelist` is not an `AdapterView` object, but a `View` object instead.
Change `thelist` to `AdapterView`.

You can temporarily downcast `thelist` if required later like this:

```
(View) thelist = ...;
(View) thelist.someMethod(args);
```